# Has a neutrino annihilation ever been recorded?

Tags: neutrinos

Can you tell me if an instance of neutrinos annnihilation has ever been observed or provoked?

The say this event is very rare, since neutrinos are produced both by beta and inverse beta decay, isn't the number of neutrinos going to grow more and more irreversibly?

Comment: There are plenty of reactions that absorb neutrinos. There is little risk that the entire universe will eventually end up as neutrinos.

Comment: you feel like expanding on that? have physicist ever provoked one?

Comment: [The original detection of neutrinos relied on just such a reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestake_experiment).

Comment: As far as I know a neutrino-antineutrino annihilation has never been observed, but I can't comment with any authority. That's why I haven't ventured an answer.